# How to change the code to move from right to left?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to change the code to move from right to left?

I want when click left button at first ,moves items left to right and when click right button moves items right to left!
I changed right float in CSS but is not working correctly!

this code starts move of right button but I want start move of left side!

I think we should change transform CSS code. But I don't know how to change this code!

```
if (e == 0) {   
    // Condition for left move and
}

if (e == 1) {
    // Condition for right move!
}
```

And XDS variable is `translateX` amount!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var itemsMainDiv = ('.MultiCarousel');
    var itemsDiv = ('.MultiCarousel-inner');
    var itemWidth = "";

    $('.leftLst, .rightLst').click(function () {
        var condition = $(this).hasClass("leftLst");
        if (condition)
            click(0, this);
        else
            click(1, this)
    });
    ResCarouselSize();
    $(window).resize(function () {
        ResCarouselSize();
    });

    //this function define the size of the items
    function ResCarouselSize() {
        var incno = 0;
        var dataItems = ("data-items");
        var itemClass = ('.item');
        var id = 0;
        var btnParentSb = '';
        var itemsSplit = '';
        var sampwidth = $(itemsMainDiv).width();
        var bodyWidth = $('body').width();
        $(itemsDiv).each(function () {
            id = id + 1;
            var itemNumbers = $(this).find(itemClass).length;
            btnParentSb = $(this).parent().attr(dataItems);
            itemsSplit = btnParentSb.split(',');
            $(this).parent().attr("id", "MultiCarousel" + id);


            if (bodyWidth >= 1200) {
                incno = itemsSplit[3];
                itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
            }
            else if (bodyWidth >= 992) {
                incno = itemsSplit[2];
                itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
            }
            else if (bodyWidth >= 768) {
                incno = itemsSplit[1];
                itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
            }
            else {
                incno = itemsSplit[0];
                itemWidth = sampwidth / incno;
            }
            $(this).css({ 'transform': 'translateX(0px)', 'width': itemWidth * itemNumbers });
            $(this).find(itemClass).each(function () {
                $(this).outerWidth(itemWidth);
            });

            $(".leftLst").addClass("over");
            $(".rightLst").removeClass("over");

        });
    }

    //this function used to move the items
    function ResCarousel(e, el, s) {
        var leftBtn = ('.leftLst');
        var rightBtn = ('.rightLst');
        var translateXval = '';
        var divStyle = $(el + ' ' + itemsDiv).css('transform');
        var values = divStyle.match(/-?[\d\.]+/g);
        var xds = Math.abs(values[4]);
        if (e == 0) {
            translateXval = parseInt(xds) - parseInt(itemWidth * s);
            $(el + ' ' + rightBtn).removeClass("over");

            if (translateXval <= itemWidth / 2) {
                translateXval = 0;
                $(el + ' ' + leftBtn).addClass("over");
            }
        }
        else if (e == 1) {
            var itemsCondition = $(el).find(itemsDiv).width() - $(el).width();
            translateXval = parseInt(xds) + parseInt(itemWidth * s);
            $(el + ' ' + leftBtn).removeClass("over");

            if (translateXval >= itemsCondition - itemWidth / 2) {
                translateXval = itemsCondition;
                $(el + ' ' + rightBtn).addClass("over");
            }
        }
        $(el + ' ' + itemsDiv).css('transform', 'translateX(' + -translateXval + 'px)');
    }

    //It is used to get some elements from btn
    function click(ell, ee) {
        var Parent = "#" + $(ee).parent().attr("id");
        var slide = $(Parent).attr("data-slide");
        ResCarousel(ell, Parent, slide);
    }

});
```

```css
.MultiCarousel { float: left; overflow: hidden; padding: 15px; width: 100%; position:relative; }
    .MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner { transition: 1s ease all; float: left; }
        .MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner .item {width: 190px; float: left;}
        .MultiCarousel .MultiCarousel-inner .item > div { text-align: center; padding:10px; margin:10px; background:#f1f1f1; color:#666;}
    .MultiCarousel .leftLst, .MultiCarousel .rightLst { position:absolute; border-radius:50%;top:calc(50% - 20px); }
    .MultiCarousel .leftLst { left:0; }
    .MultiCarousel .rightLst { right:0; }
    
        .MultiCarousel .leftLst.over, .MultiCarousel .rightLst.over { pointer-events: none; background:#ccc; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="MultiCarousel" data-items="1,3,5,6" data-slide="1" id="MultiCarousel"  data-interval="1000">
            <div class="MultiCarousel-inner">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="pad15">
                        <p class="lead">Multi Item Carousel</p>
                        <p>₹ 1</p>
                        <p>₹ 6000</p>
                        <p>50% off</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary leftLst">PREV</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary rightLst">NEXT</button>
        </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.leftLst, .rightLst').click(function () {
        var condition = $(this).hasClass("leftLst");
        if (!condition)
            click(0, this);
        else
            click(1, this)
    });
```

That should do it, add **!** before condition.

[EDIT]

My bad. Try this way: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1520q6tt/)

```
function ResCarousel(e, el, s) {
    ....
    if (e == 0) {
            translateXval = parseInt(xds) + parseInt(itemWidth * s);
            $(el + ' ' + rightBtn).removeClass("over");

            if (translateXval <= itemWidth / 2) {
                translateXval = 0;
                $(el + ' ' + leftBtn).addClass("over");
            }
        }
        else if (e == 1) {
            var itemsCondition = $(el).find(itemsDiv).width() - $(el).width();
            translateXval = parseInt(xds) - parseInt(itemWidth * s);
            $(el + ' ' + leftBtn).removeClass("over");

            if (translateXval >= itemsCondition - itemWidth / 2) {
                translateXval = itemsCondition;
                $(el + ' ' + rightBtn).addClass("over");
            }
        }
```

Invert the signs.

Comment: delete over class for better review

Comment: I edit my post! I'm sorry for not explaining completely

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem

```
if (e == 0) {
            translateXval =-Math.abs( parseInt(xds) - parseInt(itemWidth * s));

            //$(el + ' ' + rightBtn).removeClass("over");

            if (parseInt(xds) <= itemWidth / 2) {
               translateXval = 0;
                //$(el + ' ' + leftBtn).addClass("over");
           }
        }
        else if (e == 1) {
            var itemsCondition = $(el).find(itemsDiv).width() - $(el).width();
            translateXval = parseInt(xds) + parseInt(itemWidth * s);
            translateXval=-Math.abs(translateXval)
            //$(el + ' ' + leftBtn).removeClass("over");

            if (translateXval <=-Math.abs(itemsCondition)) {
                translateXval = -Math.abs(itemsCondition);
                $(el + ' ' + leftBtn).addClass("over");
            }
        }
```